# Raster Symbology is using estimated values regardless of settings. QGIS 3.28.2

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology

I am using QGIS to view a DSM and it seems to be using estimates rather than actual values, regardless of what I have toggled for the accuracy setting. Here are the settings that I'm using for my symbology: [image]

Here I have my accuracy stats set to "actual" but in a given area with a max pixel value of 96 it seems to take averages based on my scale. The further I zoom in the more my values approach 96 but I have to be very zoomed in for them to stretch all the way to show the true values in the area when I am zoomed out. I'm thinking it has something to do with the nearest neighbor resampling but I have tried both bilinear and cubic resampling to no avail. Any guesses here would be very appreciated!

here is the area at 1:3000, the min max values range up to 33 [image]

If I zoom into the area of interest it will update the min max values to be closer to the actual but still not reflecting the actual values.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the color range unchanged, use "Whole raster" as Statistics extent.

Comment: I do want it to update with the current display, but just need it to display the true min-max values in a given display rather than approximating those values, in the last three screenshots that bit of noise is present at 95 meters but it wont update the display unless it is quite zoomed in. My hunch is its doing some sort of averaging where if theres only a few pixels visible it includes those true values, but the more visible pixels the further that max value lowers from whats actually present

Comment: Maybe connected to resampling? See: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#resampling

Comment: Does it work with "Single band gray"? Maybe there is something common with this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52743.

Comment: it seems like a similar issue though for me it is still take some sort of average on single band gray, as at a certain scale it's still not including the max value of 96 and I a zoom in the max grows towards 96

Comment: to the previous comment, it may be related to resampling, though as I understand it that shouldn't impact the min/max values, I have played around with resampling to no avail